# Pasar datos de una consulta a otro activity, listview

Tags: android-studio, sql-server, android-intent, android-listview

formulé una pregunta sobre como pasar datos entre actividades, y me respondieron bien, pero mi problema ahora es que no yo no necesito pasar una cadena simple o un entero, necesito pasar una consulta SQLserver, meterla en el intent y ya pues pasarla a la otra actividad para que ahí me la muestre, pero no sé como hacerlo,pasar texto plano es fácil, pero no entiendo que hacer con una consulta SQLserver, llevo un rato intentándolo y no puedo, alguien me puede echar un cable? dejo el código por aquí, gracias!!

```
public class Listado extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
TextView idtext;
EditText etFiltrar;
String where = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado);
    setupActionBAR();
    etFiltrar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFiltrrar);

    etFiltrar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            where = etFiltrar.getText().toString();
            mostrarClientes();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMostrar);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
            idtext = (TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.id);
            Log.i("Click", position + " " + idtext.getText());
            // ESTO SOLO MUESTRA UN TOAST CON LA POSITION + ID DE TABLA
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position= " + position + " ID=" + idtext.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            **enviardatos()**;
        }
    });
    mostrarClientes();
}

public void **enviardatos**() {
    **//Pr**ocedimiento para poder pasarlo a la otra activity, aquí tendría que meter los datos de la consulta sql pero no se como..
    Intent intent = new Intent(Listado.this, ClienteEspecifico.class);
    intent.putExtra("nombre", "**CADENA SIMPLE, PERO QUIERO PASAR UNA CONSULTA** SQL");
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void setupActionBAR() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        //Mostrar el boton en el ActionBar
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("Lista de Clientes");
    }
}

public void mostrarClientes() {
    HashMap<String, String> clientes = new HashMap<>();
    ConectarHaciaSQL consql;
    consql = new ConectarHaciaSQL();
    Connection cn = consql.conexionBD();

    try {
        Statement pst = cn.createStatement();
        String sel;
        sel = "select CLI.idcliente, CLI.NombreComercial, UC.telefono1 from clientes as CLI" + " left join ubicacionesClientes as UC on UC.idcliente = CLI.idCliente ";
        if (where != "") {
            sel = sel + " where CLI.NombreComercial like '%" + where + "%'";
        }
        //sel = sel + " ORDER BY CLI.idcliente ASC";
        //Ejecuta el query del SQL
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sel);
        //Recorre la tabla del SQL
        while (rs.next()) {
            clientes.put(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));//
        }

        if (rs != null) {
        } else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No hay nada ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (rs != null)
            rs.close();

        List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_items,
                new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name});

        Iterator it = clientes.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            HashMap<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            resultMap.put("First Line", pair.getKey().toString());
            resultMap.put("Second Line", pair.getValue().toString());
            listItems.add(resultMap);
        }
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.i("Error", "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e);
    }
}
```

}

Cómo veis tengo una consulta SQL que me muestra nombres en un listview, pero ahora necesito a través de otra consulta, (supongo) como he dicho, mostrar por ejemplo nombre, teléfono y algunos datos más en un textview de otro activity
, o a poder ser cada uno en un EditText, si alguien me contesta bien le amaré. Gracias!!!

Añado la otra actividad donde quiero recojer los nuevos datos.

```
public class ClienteEspecifico extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvMostrarDatos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cliente_especifico);
    tvMostrarDatos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMostrarDatos);
    setupActionBAR();
    Bundle bundles = getIntent().getExtras(); //En este objeto es donde están los datos que hemos enviado, pero esto es una cadena simple, necesito la consulta

    String nombre = bundles.getString("nombre");
    //  Integer telefono = bundles.getInt("telefono");
    tvMostrarDatos.setText(nombre);
    //tvMostrarDatos.setText(telefono);

}
```

}

Comment: Creas una clase que tenga los mismo campos que los que vas a mostrar en el SELECT, mapeas los datos de la SQL a la clase creada y ale, ya tienes un `ArrayList<ClaseNueva> objetoConTusDatos = ResultSet.getResults()` y con eso ya te lo puedes pasar a donde quieras y utilizarlo para lo que quieras

Comment: Podrías ponerme un ejemplo sencillo con el código que te he puesto ahí? gracias!!

Comment: ¿Con pasar una consulta te refieres a pasar el String "SELECT * FROM BLABLA..."?

Comment: Sí, por ejemplo, es decir yo tendría que pasar registros de la base de datos, esa consulta por ejemplo me servirían algunos, aunque tendría que añadir alguno más

Comment: ¿Y qué problema tienes al recoger el String? y, ¿dónde lo recoges?

Comment: el problema está en que no sé como meterlo en el intent, y si directamente de un string (que en este caso es la consulta) puedo pasar los datos al otro activity

Comment: Leyendo tu respuesta de abajo entiendo que quieres pasar el usuario para ponerlo en el where de la consulta, ¿no? ¿Y podrías añadir la otra actividad?

Comment: No entiendo, lo que necesito es al clickar en cierta persona del listview, me habrá otro activity con la información de esa persona, pero para eso supongo que tengo que hacer otra consulta de todo lo que quiero rescatar de esa persona, no? pues quiero pasar esa consulta que tengo que hacer al otro activity

Comment: Ponme el código de la otra actividad y te propongo algo. (En la que quieres sacar la info del usuario en el que se hace click)

Comment: En el otro activity solo recojo una cadena simple... por ahora pero necesito datos de una consulta

Comment: Bundle bundles = getIntent().getExtras(); //En este objeto es donde están los datos que hemos enviado, pero esto es una cadena simple, necesito la consulta

        String nombre = bundles.getString("nombre");

Comment: Pues cambia `intent.putExtra("nombre", "**CADENA SIMPLE, PERO QUIERO PASAR UNA CONSULTA** SQL");` y pon la consulta `intent.putExtra("nombre", "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS");`

Comment: Intent intent = getIntent();
String sql= intent.getExtras().getString("nombre");

Comment: Asier, he probado tu respuesta pero no me recoje la información solo me muestra "select * from .."

Comment: Listo, ya está el merge hecho. Recuerda no eliminar para volver a publicar si no editar y aclarar. Ah y recuerda eliminar los comentarios obsoletos para dejar una publicación ordenada y limpia. Un saludo

Comment: Es que debería mostrar eso, la consulta. Luego tú haz con ella lo que consideres. Por favor, pon la otra actividad.

Comment: Pero no me muestra el resultado de la consulta, me muestra la consulta en sí, no sé si me explico.. Es decir en el textview de la otra actividad muestra : select CLI.idcliente,CLI.NombreComercial..., en vez de, por ejemplo: 2   ComercialAlicante. Me entiendes? Gracias!!

Comment: Claro, tienes que hacer la consulta en la nueva actividad. O eso, o la consulta la haces en la clase Listado y devuelves el resultado.

Comment: Vale, y que consulta debería hacer por ejemplo en la segunda actividad, que me parece más adecuado, además está consulta que haga me la cojerá sólo de la persona que yo haya seleccionado en el listview del anterior activity, no? podrías ponerme el ejemplo lo más certero posible que puedas en una respuesta? te lo agradecería.. ya que me está costando la vida esto

Comment: A ver, la consulta (el string) ya la tienes, se supone que la pasas por el intent. Lo que te queda por hacer es lo que haces en `mostrarClientes()`: conectar a la bdd, el statement, executeQuery, resulSet...

Comment: Tenias razón, por fin lo he sacado ahora veo que no era tan difícil... Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Como en el SELECT estás recuperando los siguientes campos:
idcliente, NombreComercial, UC.telefono1 lo primero será crear una clase con esos campos, getters y setters.

Dentro de tu clase en la parte de:

```
//Recorre la tabla del SQL
    while (rs.next()) {
        clientes.put(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
    }
```

Tendríamos que añadir lo siguiente:

```
    //Recorre la tabla del SQL
    //Declararlo al inicio del método y lo inicializamos justo encima del (rs.next());
    ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listaClaseNueva = new ArrayList<ClaseNueva>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        ClaseNueva claseNueva = new ClaseNueva();
        clientes.put(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));//
        claseNueva.setIdCliente(rs.getString("idcliente");
        claseNueva.setNombreComercial(rs.getString("nombreComercial");
        claseNueva.setTelefono1 (rs.getString("telefono1");
        listaClaseNueva.add(claseNueva);
    }
```

Si además de esto, el método `mostrarClientes()` en vez de ser `void` es:

```
public ArrayList<ClaseNueva> mostrarClientes() {
  /**
   * Todo el código
   */
  return listaClaseNueva;
}
```

Te estaría devolviendo la lista con tus clientes que lo podrías "pasar" donde te hiciera falta, espero que te ayude.

Comment: Claro pero como haría la otra clase devolviendo esos campos?

Answer (score 0):

En la primera actividad, coges el resultado de la consulta del `textview`, lo pasas a un `string`

```
String resultado consulta= idText.getText().toString();
```

Después lo mandas a la otra `activity` con `putExtra` de `intent`.

Si lo que quieres es hacer la consulta (y no el resultado) en otra actividad, te diría que es más simple hacerlo desde esa `activity` que estar pasando información de una a otra.

*Actualizo la respuesta al ver tu comentario:*

Entonces lo que necesitas es llamar a la informacion en el `setOnItemClickListener ---> onItemClick` del `listview` , (a los text views) y hacer los `.getText().toString();` pasarlo a un `String` y este `String` enviarlo ... Así guardas los datos de dónde has pulsado en un `String` que enviaras posteriormente ya que después de guardarlos haces el `intent` , pasas al nuevo `activity` con los datos del ítem que has pulsado en el `listview`

*Actualizo la respuesta al ver tu comentario con un ejemplo:*

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
```

// Aquí tienes que llamar al cursor para relacionar columnas con registros y que lo puedas usar con el listview.
// Y una vez selecciones un item recogerá los datos en los que pulses.

```
            TextView infoConsulta = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.infoConsulta);
                            String datosConsulta = infoConsulta.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent (adapterView.getContext(), SegundaActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("keyDatosConsulta", datosConsulta);


            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: La cosa es, al clickar en un nombre de persona en el listview, quiero que se me abra información acerca de esa persona en otro activity, cómo lo hago

Comment: Estoy intentándolo pero no lo consigo, podrías ponerme un ejemplo? Creo que tu respuesta me podría servir.. lo siento y gracias

Comment: Claro, edito en un momento la respuesta con un ejemplo que utilizo yo en algo similar ! :)

Comment: Gracias, por lo que entiendo hago un String con la consulta dentro, y luego en el intent.putExtra llamo a esa variable String, pero de esta manera me muestra la consulta tal cual.., espero tu ejemplo bro!

Comment: Vale ahora entiendo algo mejor, estas enviando el string de la consulta, envía los datos (de un textview o editext) pero una vez obtenidos...

Comment: Es decir tú me dices que primero pase la consulta a un textview por ejemplo, y después pase los datos de ese textview a la otra activity, si es así el problema está en que yo no puedo poner otro textview en la activity que contiene ya un listview con la lista de personas, la cosa sería que a raíz del listview que tengo, cuando clicke en un item  (persona), me muestre en otro activity más información de esa persona en concreto, que yo tengo la información en diferentes tablas del sql, por ejemplo.. Gracias!

Comment: No no, si lo que digo es lo que quieres hacer jajaja A ver cómo te lo explico...Vale, ya se lo que pasa, la movida es que estamos cogiendo el String de la consulta, lo que tienes que hacer es llamar al cursor de tu base de datos ... Actualizo en mi respuesta

Comment: Me está costando entonces entenderlo.. soy un poco nuevo en esto y estoy iendo un poco a piñón, gracias por la paciencia

Comment: Tranquilo, pensaba que esos datos ya los sacabas, fue confusión mía ...

Comment: La verdad, me he perdido más aún... jajaja pero agradezco tu respuesta supongo que ya será problema mío

Comment: Voy a editarla para que solo salga lo del cursor , pero vamos lo único que tienes que hacer es llamar dentro de cuando haces click, al cursor de tu bd que relacione esa columna con el registro que sea... Y lo de coger los datos y pasarlos ya estaría... Solo te queda eso

Comment: Solo te queda eso, dale a resuelta para que si lo ve otra persona sepa cómo hacerla, espero haberte ayudado... Lo dicho solo te queda llamar al cursor de tu clase gestora de bd o bien de otra manera si no tienes clases de bd! Eso depende de cada proyecto ... Pero tal cual, con el cursor sería funcional... Yo hago eso que haces tú y paso los datos a un formulario que los muestra una vez pulsas en el listview anteriormente...